# Put in X axis counter timer from integer in Excel Chart

Tags: excel, vba, charts

In my Excel chart, the Xaxis shows sequential integers representing seconds in multiples of 10:

10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 and so on

How to show in this Xaxis minutes and seconds like this:

00:00 00:10 00:20 00:30 00:40 00:50 01:00 01:10 01:20 01:30 and so on

I use the VBA below to generate the chart.

```vb
Sub NewChart()
    'Create a chart
        
    Sheets(1).Select 'Select the active Sheet
    
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
   
    LastLine = Sheets(2).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim MaxScale As Integer
    Dim MTotal As Integer
    Dim Aprox As Integer
    Dim vName As String
    vName = Sheets(2).Range("B3")
    
    Dim Qx As Integer
    Qx = LastLine - 1
    Dim Rangg As Integer
    Rangg = (LastLine * 10) - 60
    MTotal = Rangg
    MaxScale = Rangg + 20
        
    With ActiveChart
        .ChartType = xlXYScatter
        'Set data source range.
        .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets(2).Range("A5:A" & Qx & ",B5:B" & Qx & ",E5:E" & Qx & ",H5:H" & Qx & ", K5:K" & Qx & ", N5:N" & Qx & ", Q5:Q" & Qx) ', 'PlotBy:=xlRows
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = vName '"2-7μm"
         
        'The Parent property is used to set properties of the Chart.
        With .Parent
          .Top = 2
          .Left = 2
          .Width = 540
          .Height = 252
          .Name = "2micron"
        End With
        
        ActiveChart.Legend.Select
        With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
            .NameComplexScript = "Tahoma"
            .NameFarEast = "Tahoma"
            .Name = "Tahoma"
        End With
        
        .Axes(xlCategory).MajorTickMark = xlInside
        .Axes(xlCategory).MinorTickMark = xlInside
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).Select
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).TickLabels.Font.Size = 5
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).TickLabels.Font.Name = "Tahoma"
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).TickLabels.Font.Bold = msoTrue
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Time (seconds)"
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Font.Size = 11
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Font.Bold = msoTrue
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Font.Name = "Tahoma"
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MinorUnitIsAuto = False
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MajorUnit = 300
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MinorUnit = 60
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MaximumScale = MaxScale
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MinimumScale = 0
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasMajorGridlines = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasMinorGridlines = True
        .Axes(xlCategory).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        
        .Axes(xlValue).MajorTickMark = xlInside
        .Axes(xlValue).MinorTickMark = xlInside
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).Select
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasMajorGridlines = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasMinorGridlines = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).TickLabels.Font.Size = 11
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).TickLabels.Font.Name = "Tahoma"
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).TickLabels.Font.Bold = msoTrue
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Y axis Legend"
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Font.Size = 11
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Font.Name = "Tahoma"
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Font.Bold = msoTrue
        .Axes(xlValue).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)

        .Legend.IncludeInLayout = False
        .Legend.Select
        Selection.Position = xlTop
        Selection.Font.Size = 11
        Selection.Font.Name = "Tahoma"
        Selection.Font.Bold = msoTrue
              
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("2micron").ScaleWidth 1, msoFalse, _
            msoScaleFromTopLeft
            
        ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
        ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
        Selection.Left = 2
        Selection.Top = 2
        Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 13.2
        Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name = "Tahoma"
        Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoTrue
        ActiveChart.Legend.Select
        Selection.Left = 180
        Selection.Top = 2
        With Selection.Format.Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent1
            .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
            .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
        End With
        ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
        Selection.Top = 22
        Selection.Left = 20
        Selection.Height = 207
        Selection.Width = 540
        Selection.Border.LineStyle = xlSolid
        Selection.Border.Color = vbBlack
        Selection.Interior.Color = vbWhite
    End With

    Call f_l2m1(1, 8, RGB(0, 176, 240))
    Call f_l2m1(2, 3, RGB(255, 0, 0))
    Call f_l2m1(3, 1, RGB(255, 0, 255))
    Call f_l2m1(4, 2, RGB(153, 0, 255))
    Call f_l2m1(5, 4, RGB(153, 0, 255))
    Call f_l2m1(6, 9, RGB(146, 208, 80))

    Range("a22").Select
End Sub


Sub f_l2m1(LineNo, MStyle, vRGB)

    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("2micron").Chart
                              
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(LineNo).Select
        With Selection
            .MarkerStyle = MStyle
            .MarkerSize = 7
            .MarkerForegroundColor = vRGB
        End With
        Selection.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
        Selection.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
        Selection.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = vRGB
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your data from whole number seconds to actual times:
Divide by 86400 (60sec/min*60min/hr*24hr/day)

Use number format MM:SS

Make sure chart is an XY chart. X axis should pick up MM:SS format from data, but if not you can format it by formatting the axis.

Comment: 86400 OK - MM:SS OK - .ChartType = xlXYScatter OK - formatting the axis  ?  Teach me please.